# programming spare key on 2003 ford ranger edge

Tags: starting, ranger

i have a 2003 ford ranger edge 3.0 .i tried to program a spare key using the 2 existing keys in the vehicle without success..i followed the instructions via you tube put the first key in turned the ignition on until the lights went out  did the second key the same way then put the new or spare key in the lights went out waited a minute then tried the new spare key and it didn't work..any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: I suggest that you check the workshop manual for the correct procedure : I would not rate y**tube as a reliable resource. I can tell you that the procedure for my car (Ford stable 2005) is completely different and more challenging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have found so far.
Other than the instructions below you will need a super star new generation tester to get it programmed.

[image]